# Keep JNLP unsigned and allow <all-permissions/>

Tags: java, jnlp

I have made a small java swing application that I want to share with a friend of mine. My application accesses the user's file tree and then writes a file and places it on the user's drive.

Right now I am testing the jnlp on my laptop and the error i am getting is this: **Found unsigned entry in resource**

I have added these lines to my `.jnlp`

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
 </security>
```

I understand that have to add signed code but that has no use to me since the application is only between me and my friend. This guy [here](http://www.dallaway.com/acad/webstart/) has done something like a fake signing.
How can I do that? How exactly is code signed?

Comment: BTW - why did you make it `all-permissions` in the first place?  What specific things could it not do while sand-boxed?  I ask because the JNLP API provides a number of functions to **sand-boxed** JWS apps. (e.g. printing, persistence, file-system access..).  See some of the other examples in the demo. page I linked, for more details.

Comment: yeah my application accesses the user's file tree and then writes a file and places it on the user's drive. that's the only thing i need permission for.

Comment: Try the **sand-boxed** version of the same code I pointed you to.  It can read & write from the local file-system & **does not *need* to be digitally signed.**  (The only reason the code is signed is for the version that is deployed as trusted.)

Comment: I will try it. do you have a specification for the sandbox specific methods and classes?

Comment: What do you mean by 'specification'?  Did you try the sand-boxed version of the app.?

Comment: I meant the javadoc. but i haven't tried yet. but will soon enough. i am in class right now.

Comment: The JNLP API will not give paths, so getting the directory is not an option.  Instead you might offer the user a [FileOpenService.openMultiFileDialog()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileOpenService.html#openMultiFileDialog%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) so they can select resources from within the directory.  BTW - more information is better than less.  You told me 'what' you are doing, but not the 'why'.  If I knew the why (as in a program feature), I could give better answers to your questions.

Comment: what will be used instead of [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44217765/code_Snippet.txt) code snippet, because ,as far as I understand, I cannot use JFileChooser.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added a few more LOCs to the snippet. My actual objective is to gather all the names of the `.jpg` files inside the directory and then write those names to a file named `.hidden`. The effect is that on the Nautilus File Manager the files become hidden without altering them so as to not ruin them for Windows. This helps me hide the album art files on nautilus without affecting them on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How exactly is code signed?

Here is an [example](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  The [filetest.zip](http://pscode.org/jws/filetest.zip) contains `build.xml`, source & JNLP.  The build file demonstrates how to sign the code with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have to ask. how will i create the `build.xml`? and where is the `build.xml` file called? in the `.jnlp` or the `.jar`?

Comment: i have expanded it. I just don't know how to make my own build.xml and where to place it. I also see that you added the genkey and that is where the certificate is made. but what i want to know is how do i put this in my build.xml. and once again, how is the build.xml written or generated?

Please bear with me, I am a novice at Java Deployment and i have no idea how Ant or any other build tools work.

Comment: See also [Generating Self Signed Certificate with Keytool](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GeneratingSelfSignedCertificateWithKeytool).

Comment: @trashgod where will the `.cert` file be placed?

Comment: Wherever you put it: [`-export -rfc -file cert_file`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html).